# How to configure spring security to authenticate with multiple idp servers (one is custom authentication server and other is OKTA) based on header?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, idp

I have a spring-boot application which uses spring-security integration for authentication.

And I need to implement spring-security configurations to handle authentication from multiple IDP servers - one is OKTA & another one is the custom auth implementation.

The current set-up of the application uses only the custom auth implementation, and My goal is to include OKTA auth configurations in the same application. The request URIs are same, but we need to choose the authentication type based on the header value.

Comment: What did you try? Have you searched for any resources on the web? We can help you with a concrete problem you might have during coding. The SO community is not here to write code for you.

Comment: You should look into this [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers] article.

Comment: @tiborK The URL is messed up. SO automatically highlights URLs without formatting so just write https://example.com . Use the square brackets only if you want to use a different label for the URL `[like this](https://example.com)` [like this](https://example.com). If you just wrap an URL with square brackets it will include the closing bracket in the URL which may break it: [https://example.com]

Comment: Thank you @GACy20 for pointing that out. Here is the proper link -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers